# how to run squish qt test cases on pyqt5 application running on source code

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, squish

I am new to squish ,so please help me solve this issue .

1. Is there any way to attach pyqt5 application running on source code (.py) file as a aut in squish for qt, I am using this command to run pyqt5 application from squish installation bin folder(startaut.exe --wrapper=Qt --port=8050 c:\projects\app.py).
2. how to run squish qt test cases on pyqt5 application running on source code.

Comment: Why not execute a Python interpreter with the ```startaut```?

Comment: How to execute python interpreter with startaut

Comment: Just specify executable and arguments, like ```startaut --verbose --port=9999 C:\Python38\python.exe app.py```.

Comment: Regarding "Running Squish test case with PyQt based AUT": You are using startaut. This implies that you know about attaching to running application. You are probably reading https://doc.qt.io/squish/attaching-to-running-applications.html. After executing startaut, your test script can attach to the running application on port 9999, via attachToApplication(). (There is no difference whether this is PyQt or Qt, or if it is any other Squish edition.) Here is a variation of the info in the manual: https://kb.froglogic.com/squish/qt/howto/attaching-to-running-apps/